# how can I verify values in a dropdown using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I would like to ask how can I verify if the sample values below are present in a dropdown.

See code below.

```
public bool AnimePresent()
        {
            bool match = false;
            string[] animal = { "Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Mouse" };
            IWebElement dropdown = this.testObject.WebDriver.FindElement(dropdownItems);
            SelectElement check = new SelectElement(dropdown);
            IList<IWebElement> allOptions = check.Options;

            //foreach(IWebElement option in check.Options)
            //{
                for (int i = 0; i < animal.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (allOptions.Contains(animal[i]))
                    {
                        match = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        match = false;
                    }
                }
            //}
            return match;
        }
```

I'm getting an error; cannot convert from string to OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.

Do I miss any?

Thank you.

Comment: Yep sure can...

Comment: Find a selector that will get all of those elements as a collection of WebElements, and check the value of those is what you expect. Can't be more specific than that with the lack of detail in the question, hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build a java code. try to convert it in c#
Try to do something like below, use shorting also for more specific answer :-

```
 String[] a = {"Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Mouse", "Ant"};
         List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.id("com.partnerfusion.travelpass:id/hotelName"));
         for(WebElement e : myElements) {
                if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(a[i])) {
                    System.out.println("This value is equal="+e.getText());
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("This value is not equal ="+e.getText());
                }
         }
```

Hope it will help you :)